# QT: garbled message

Tags: qt

Environment: ubuntu + Qt

Running in Qt IDE, it's all fine. After "qmake" and "make", I get an executable file. When running it, some of the messages in chinese  went wrong. How to solve?

Screenshots are shown below:

In Qt IDE:
[image: In Qt IDE:]

Executable file:
[image: Executable file:]

Comment: I just leave it here - [Qt for Linux/X11 - Deployment](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html) ...

Comment: Best solution is to follow this. https://github.com/probonopd/linuxdeployqt/releases

Comment: Are you using QML? If not, make sure the strings are like L"".